# filtering contents of radgridview

Tags: filter, filtering, radgridview

i have a problem with filtering th contents of my radgridview.

here's my code

```
private void Filter_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FilterDescriptor filter = new FilterDescriptor("Name", FilterOperator.Contains, (RadGridView1.SelectedItem as Person).Name);
    RadGridView1.FilterDescriptors.Add(filter);
}
```

it only filters the "Name" column. i want it to filter the data based on the value of the cell clicked... i have to get the column name of the cell clicked and replace it to "Name" in my code...

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

here's the code to **filter**:

```
FilterDescriptor filter = new FilterDescriptor(RadGridView1.CurrentCell.Column.UniqueName, FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, RadGridView1.CurrentCell.Value);
RadGridView1.FilterDescriptors.Add(filter);
```

here's the code to **remove filter**:

```
RadGridView1.FilterDescriptors.Clear();
```

**RadGridView1** is the name of the radgridview.